# Расширенный поиск Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Появился вопрос по созданию поиска как на [этом сайте](http://spb-n.ru/), только на
wоrdpress...Можете подсказать, реально это или нет? И где можно про такое вычитать? Может быть есть плагины?

Comment: а информация о квартирах в доп полях лежит?

Comment: не знаю...скорее всего да...с помощью плагина custom field

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `custom fields`. Это даст возможность задавать записям дополнительные параметры. В месте вывода необходимо сформировать форму для поиска, используя параметры (имя и тип его значения) пользовательских полей. На этой же странице принимать и обрабатывать параметры формы поиска. Если их нет (пользователь поиском не пользовался), то выводить, например, последние предложения, а если они есть, тогда по заданным пользователем параметрам сделать вручную выборку из БД.

[Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

[Выборка постов используя пользовательские поля записи](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

[Плагин для custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/F8LrLA-4uX30cLYVJJ2tCRqZWc-g)

Можно использовать примочки javascript и ajax для красоты.